# Is this a method or a function?

Tags: swift, function, methods

Am I correct in assuming that `getDataPoint()` is a method as opposed to a function when used in this context?

```
class Globals: NSObject{
   static let sharedInstance = Globals()

   func getDataPoint() -> Int {
      var theValue: Int
      //Some JSON code here
      return theValue
   }
}

class GameScene: SKScene{
   override func didMove(to: view: SKView){
      let globals = Globals.sharedInstance()

      var x = globals.getDataPoint() //Is a method?
   }
}
```

But if I used within the Globals class, I would call it a function.

```
 class Globals: NSObject{
   static let sharedInstance = Globals()

   func foo() {
      print(\(getDataPoint())) //Is a function?
   }

   func getDataPoint() -> Int {
      var theValue: Int
      //Some JSON code here
      return theValue
   }
}
```

Comment: It's attached to a type – therefore it's a method. But methods are still functions.

Comment: @Hamish That's exactly what I thought, but see my edit. What then?

Comment: @Sulthan What do you mean everything returns a value?  What does `foo()` return in my example?

Comment: Methods are simply functions that are defined inside of a class. In the class definition they look like a regular function. To use them outside the class you would need to use the dot notation `Globals.foo()`. (At least for a regular kind of class - I don't know Swift)

Comment: And the deleted comment about functions returning values and methods not is a rough heuristic that seems kind of out of date. It is certainly not the case in the languages I know (Python and R)

Comment: @HFBrowning I agree, the deleted comment did not seem to apply at all.

Comment: Taken from the OP's comments: "That's exactly what I thought, but see my edit. What then?", "What would make it a function?". By **your** definition, what is the #1 key difference? Please, make it something absolute. (Or at the very least, state how this is specific somehow and not some *style* debate.) If most times anyone can interchange method/function, before I can understand the question (much less any answer), I need *your* definitive distinction between the two.

Answer (score 2):

A method is not "opposed to a function" so the question is meaningless. A method *is* a function — a function declared at the top level of a type declaration.

```
func function() {}
class Class {
    func method() {}
    func anotherMethod() {
        func function() { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s a method. This is just an artefact of Swift’s shorthand for referring to methods and properties without the `self.` qualifier.

```
func foo() {
   print(\(getDataPoint()))
}
```

is exactly the same as writing

```
func foo() {
   print(\(self.getDataPoint()))
}
```

Comment: What would make it a function?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup methods *are* functions. I assume you mean *free functions* in your question and comment; those are functions you define outside of the scope of a type.